# Where should I place css and js code in MasterPage.Master of ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I need to reference css and js in *MasterPage.Master* file of ASP.NET,  the code A can work well, but Visual Studio displays a warning information, you can see Image 1.

BTW, the code B can't get correct result.

**Code A**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="LinkTabs.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js")%>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Js/my.js")%>'></script>

<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Css/Main.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />

<head runat="server">
    <title>Open multiple links in new tabs at once</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="container">

        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Code B**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="LinkTabs.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Open multiple links in new tabs at once</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js")%>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Js/my.js")%>'></script>

    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Css/Main.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="container">

        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Image 1**

[image]

**Add Content:**

Answered by AI, you can see Image 2, is it right?

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: "the code B can't get correct result." , please be more descriptive, what is the actual result? What is the expected result? Why use `resolveUrl` at all? Why not use a root relative path : `<script type="text/javascript" src='/Js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B looks to be correct in regards to the script files, but looks VERY wrong in regards to the content template.

Your content template needs to come AFTER everything.

So, say your scripts (in the head), then your main menu etc. in the master page, that goes in the form tag. And at the VERY bottom, after everything else you would want to have in the master page.

So, you can have "more" then one content area.

so, say this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Open multiple links in new tabs at once</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

  -- all of the main page content here - menu bar etc.

    <div id="container">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>



    </div>


</form>
```

So, your MainContent place holder needs to go rather near the bottom, so everything on the main page "form" is above that last content place holder, which of course when you "create" a new page with master, then you wind up with JUST 2 content templates (the first one - header, which I presume you will VERY rare use), and then the MainContent stuff in which you place the regular stuff that you would have in the child page.

The child page(s) of course don't ever thus then have a "form" tag, and you only allowed one per page anyway.

So, really, the layout of a single page (without master page), has your extra scripts placed in the head section.

but, with a master page, and those scripts, then again, yes, that goes in the head section. In fact, I in most cases prefer some extra js routines I have, and I place them right below the end form tag in master.

So B looks better for the placement of the js reference libraries, but it looks to be missing a "main content" area that will "hold" the content of each page you create, and that generally going to be "very" near the bottom of the master page - right before the closing form tag.

I "assume" that the posted B example was just for this question, since it missing the main content template for each page.

to be fair, I never really messed around a whole lot with this stuff, since I always started out with a existing template that includes the defaulted bootstrap menu.

Comment: It is fine but you have the jQuery in there 2 times, once at the top, and then again at the bottom. Those library scripts belong at the top. Your code and scripts as a general rule tends to be placed VERY last in the web page. (so your code that may well use jQuery, or those other script libraries can do so. So, "your" own page script code should be at the VERY bottom, since then such script can use controls on the page. Those script libraries like bootstrap or jQuery go at the top as you have, but your example ALSO has the jQuery scripts again at the bottom (remove bottom duplicated).